# Django bootstrap to have both call a view and modal in same anchor tag

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-modal

I am using Django and pretty new to it. My purpose is to trigger an asynchronous view from the template and stay in the same page showing a pop up that the process is triggered.
I searched a lot for a solution but couldn't work it out.

I am able to stay in the same page and trigger the view asynchronously using Celery but my problem is my modal is displaying the content of my web page and not the content I have mentioned in the modal content.

I am passing the view in the anchor tag href and modal in data-target.

Below is the code of my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>DashBoard</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topNavBar">
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DashBoard</a>
        </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="#" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Reports
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="#" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Projects
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="">
                <li class="">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'update-field' %}" data-target="#myModal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Update-Fields
                </a>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Field Param Update</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Update is triggered in the backend. An email will be sent when done.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Logout
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Here "update-field" is the view which is been called to trigger the background process. Any help will be grateful. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
[I am getting the below in my modal which is same as my webpage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcXml.jpg)

Comment: Actually I am not able to reproduce your problem. It seems to work fine for me. Can you elaborate?  See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhk217/ubhLzf4s/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the closure of the above issue did the following changes:

in the template, moved the modal code to separate html template:

```
<li class="">
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class="modal-content"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <a data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'update-field' %}" data-target="#myModal">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Update-Fields
     </a>
 </li>
```

```html
<!-- modal.html -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{ title }}</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>{{ body }}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>

<script>
   $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
       location.reload();});     // reloads the current page
</script>
```

```py
# views.py

class UpdateFields(UpdateView):
    def get(self, request):
        updateparams.delay()
        context = {
            'title': 'Initiating task...',
            'body': 'Field parameters update has started. An email will be sent when its complete.'
        }
        return render(request, 'app/modal.html', context)
```

```py
# urls.py

url(r'^update/', views.UpdateFields.as_view(), name='update-field')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript/JQuery, you can trigger both events on click of the `<a>` tag.
Use the following to trigger the modal through JS.

```
$(modalid).modal("show");
```

First im adding an `id` to refer to the `<a>` tag easily in JS and removing the `data-toggle="modal"`, because we will trigger the modal through JS. So the `<a>` becomes :

```
<a id="triggerEvents" href="{% url 'update-field' %}" data-target="#myModal">
```

In your **javascript** file add the following.

```
$("#triggerEvents").on("click", function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  var modalid = $(this).data("target");
  var url = $(this).attr("href");

  $(modalid).modal("show"); // Triggering bootstrap modal.

  // Do the asynchronous part here.
});
```

Maybe Celery is causing some issues. You can also use [**jquery.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to run asynchronous requests.

Documentation on [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: yes, when i try without the view it works fine, but not with the href. Is celery causing the issue, I am novice here, so not sure, but shouldn't celery be kicking off after the view is called (since celery has nothing to do with the template) and modal should be triggered before that? 

Also, I edited my post with the current content I am getting in the modal.

Comment: Well, the HTML or CSS isnt the problem. It's probably in your JS or your Django view or Celery (I dont use celery, ergo have no clue how it works) . So if you can provide the code of your JS and/or Django view I can look into it.

Comment: Or you can use `jquery.ajax()` for asynchronous processing. That's what I use in my work and have not had any issues. I can provide a sample code of how to implement it with Django.

Comment: thanks @Rithwik , I was able to figure out the issue from your comment :). The problem was with the Django view return statement. I created a template for modal and now rendering that template for the pop up. thanks again :D

Comment: do you know a way if I want to redirect my page to some other page when the modal pop up is closed?

Comment: `$('#yourModalID').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
//Redirecte to another page here. });` . This should do it.